# Can a set have an odd number of open and closed sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ok, well the empty set is obviously the trivial case.

But can any other sets have an odd number of open and closed sets?  I'm presuming not since for an open and closed set C, X\C is also open and closed by definition.  So we would need that X\C=C which is only the case with the empty set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a non-empty space with a finite number of clopen sets, then $X$ must have an even number of clopen sets, because (as you point out) clopen sets come in complementary pairs. Of course a space can also have infinitely many clopen sets; familiar examples of such spaces are $\Bbb Q$, the space of rational numbers with the usual topology, $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, the space of irrational numbers with the usual topology, the middle-thirds Cantor set, and the subspace

$$\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$

of the line with the usual topology.

Comment: Cheers Brian for the speedy response.  I'll close this if possible.

Comment: @user70147: You should be able to delete it, since the answer hans’t been upvoted.